# Best way to handle unique constraints when using Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, exception, unique-constraint

I'm using Entity Framework 4.0 to access data in a table with a unique column constraint.  If the constraint is violated, an exception occurs when I call SaveChanges(), as expected.  My question is whether I should allow the exception to be thrown in the first place.  I could alternatively do a select to avoid inserting the duplicate data (I assume a transaction would be necessary).

What's the generally accepted best practice in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoiding an exception is usually a good idea - throwing an exception is a rather elaborate and time and resource intensive operation. So if you can easily check whether a unique key value already exists, then I would probably do that. Assuming you have a unique index or unique constraint on that column at the database level, then (at least for SQL Server) already have an index on that column, so checking for a specific value would be fairly simple and would not have a huge performance impact.

The other question is: how often do you think this would happen? Once a day? Once every couple of weeks? Several times a minute? If it happens only fairly infrequently - once in a blue moon - I wouldn't bother trying to check first - in that case, just let the exception happen and handle it.

So I guess it's really a matter of how expensive is it to check first, and how often does it happen? If you can check it very easily --> do so, by all means! But if it's a rather elaborate operation to check, and it happens only very rarely, then just handle the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the common sense answer; this is pretty much what I was thinking.  Since constraint violations are rare in this case, I'll leave it as is.

Comment: Hmmm... I cannot agree. Throwing an exception is *not* as expensive as a query to the database. That said, you should query the database prior to insert/update operation that could result in the unique constraint violation.

Comment: @CodeMonkeyKing That's the point. If you query the database before inserting, you will ALWAYS have and extra round trips penalty and even so, an insert could happen between your queries and invalidate the first one. Like Marc said, check if this type of exceptions are rare in your system and if so, just let the database handle it.